# Converting c++ struct to c# struct

Tags: c#, c++, struct

Can anybody tell me how do I convert the following struct to c#

```
typedef struct DES_ks
{
    union
    {
        DES_cblock cblock;
        /* make sure things are correct size on machines with
         * 8 byte longs */
        DES_LONG deslong[2];
    } ks[16];
} DES_key_schedule
```

Comment: Well, you could tell us what type `DES_cblock` is. I'm assuming `DES_LONG` is a simple integral type, but it would be helpful if you could tell us what that is too.

Comment: Oops..sorry typedef unsigned char DES_cblock[8] is DES_cblock and DES_LONG is unsigned long

Answer (score 5):

You will need to look up the typedef's for DES_cblock and DES_LONG to translate this. However, to get you started, you'll want to read up on [`StructLayoutAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). The way to translate C unions into C# is to use an explicit layout structure:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct DES_ks
{
  [FieldOffset(0)]
  public DES_cblock cblock;
  [FieldOffset(0)]
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
  public DES_LONG[] deslong;
}
```

Thanks to @Konrad for fixing my temporary insanity; because you want to produce a union, you need all of the fields to overlap in memory. This is achieved in C# by telling the compiler to lay them out at the same offset, in this case 0.

Answer (score 0):

[C# does not have unions.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/60150e7b-665a-49a2-8e2e-2097986142f3/). The closest you can come is using FieldOffset. However, if your struct isn't being passed directly to external functions, you're likely better off using a more OO approach. I'd suggest just creating a struct with arrays of both types and set the one you aren't using to null.

Comment: This is not accurate, [LayoutKind] works just fine in regular C# code as well.

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as saying it worked "fine", but it does work.